# No puedo pasar variable a expresion regular con JS

Tags: javascript, string, regex

Necesito ayuda con pasar variable a una expresion regular.

Primero pruebo con este código:

```
let ipif = text.match(/(?<=tnl:IPIF)[\s\S]*(?=\/VLANIF-3)/g);
```

con esta expresión me funciona correctamente y me encuentra el texto deseado pero ahora necesito pasar una variable así que hago lo siguiente:

```
let vlan = "VLANIF-3";

let patron =  ("/(?<=tnl:IPIF)[\\s\\S]*(?=\\/"+vlan+")/g");
```

al visualizar el patrón concatenado con la variable se ve igual al usado con éxito `/(?<=tnl:IPIF)[\s\S]*(?=\/VLANIF-3)/g` y luego lo aplico con **match()** y no me entrega nada...

```
let ipif = text.match(patron);
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

acá el texto :

```
<managedObject class="com.koko.srbts.tnl:ETHIF_R" version="TNL20C_2009_012" distName="MRBTS-100030/TNLSVC-1/TNL-1/ETHSVC-1/ETHIF-1/ETHIF_R-1" operation="create">      <p name="macAddr">80:a8:fe:1f:eb:21</p>    </managedObject>    <managedObject class="com.koko.srbts.tnl:VLANIF" version="TNL20C_2007_009" distName="MRBTS-100030/TNLSVC-1/TNL-1/ETHSVC-1/ETHIF-1/VLANIF-1" operation="create">      <p name="userLabel">Servicio 3</p>      <p name="vlanId">402</p>    </managedObject>    <managedObject class="com.koko.srbts.tnl:VLANIF" version="TNL20C_2007_002" distName="MRBSS-100030/TNLSVC-1/TNL-1/ETHSVC-1/ETHIF-1/VLANIF-2" operation="create">      <p name="userLabel">OyM</p>      <p name="vlanId">400</p>    </managedObject>    <managedObject class="com.koko.srbts.tnl:VLANIF" version="TNL20C_2007_002" distName="MRBSS-100030/TNLSVC-1/TNL-1/ETHSVC-1/ETHIF-1/VLANIF-3" operation="create">      <p name="userLabel">Servicio 2</p>      <p name="vlanId">403</p>    </managedObject>    <managedObject class="com.koko.srbts.tnl:ETHIF" version="TNL20C_2007_002" distName="MRBSS-100030/TNLSVC-1/TNL-1/ETHSVC-1/ETHIF-2" operation="create">      <p name="linkSelectorDN">MRBSS-100030/TNLSVC-1/TNL-1/ETHSVC-1/L2SWI-1/BRGPRT-1</p>    </managedObject>"<managedObject class="com.koko.srbts.tnl:IPIF" version="TNL20C_2007_002" distName="MRBSS-100030/TNLSVC-1/TNL-1/IPNO-1/IPIF-2" operation="create">      <p name="interfaceDN">MRBSS-100030/TNLSVC-1/TNL-1/ETHSVC-1/ETHIF-1/VLANIF-3</p><p name="ipMtu">1496</p></managedObject>';
```

Comment: ¿Y cual es el valor de `text`? Lo digo para poder hacer pruebas y ver si funciona.

Comment: prueba usando el constructor de expresiones regulares así: `let patron = new RegExp("(?<=tnl:IPIF)[\\s\\S]*(?=\\/"+vlan+"), 'g')`

Comment: Bien Pipe solo faltaba una comilla antes de la coma MUCHAS GRACIAS!!

Comment: @Pipe Por favor, desarrolla una respuesta, es una buena solución, así no quedará pendiente y Cristian deberia aceptarla cuando la publiques

Comment: @Cristian: Deberias aceptar la respuesta de Pipe para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede pendiente para siempre. Pásate por el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y mirate este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) donde explican como y porque se deben aceptar las respuestas válidas, gracias por tu colaboración.

Comment: Gracias masterguru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, lo que estás haciendo aqui:

```
let ipif = text.match(/(?<=tnl:IPIF)[\s\S]*(?=\/VLANIF-3)/g);
```

Es declarar una expresion regular directamente (la parte que empieza por / y luego termina con /g.
Eso no es un string, es una forma de escribir una expresion regular directamente en javascript.

Por lo tanto no puedes concatenar cosas (porque no es un string)

Aquí casi lo logras. pero el problema es que ahora incluiste el delimitador de expresion regular dentro del string

```
let patron = "/(?<=tnl:IPIF)[\\s\\S]*(?=\\/"+vlan+")/g"; 
let ipif = text.match(patron);
```

Lo que puedes hacer es usar el constructor de `RegExp` que si permite pasarle un string concatenado y devuelve una expresión regular.

```
let patron = new RegExp("(?<=tnl:IPIF)[\\s\\S]*(?=\\/"+vlan+")", 'g')
let ipif = text.match(patron);
```

Comment: Gracias Pipe con el constructor me resultó bien ,saludos

Comment: Hay que tener cuidado cuando se agrega un texto literal a un regex (especialmente si lo ingresa el usuario!). Lo ideal sería escapar este texto.